# CakePHP 2.4.4 isAuthorized() not working properly

Tags: cakephp, admin

I am using the CakeDC users plugin and I am having trouble getting only admins to be able to view the admin section as it stands any registered user can access admin.  what am i doing wrong?

**AppController.php**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Auth' => array('authorize' => array('Controller')
        )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
        // Any registered user can access public functions
        if (empty($this->request->params['admin'])) {
            return true;
        }

        // Only admins can access admin functions
        if (isset($this->request->params['admin'])) {
            return (bool)($user['role'] === 'admin');
        }

        // Default deny
        return false;
    }

    public function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->allow("display");
        if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
            $this->layout = 'loggedin';
        }


    }

}
```

**UsersController.php** (from the CakeDC users plugin controller)

```
//other code here
    public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
        return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }
//other code here
```

**routes.php**

```
Router::connect('/users', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'));
Router::connect('/users/index/*', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'));
Router::connect('/users/:action/*', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'));
Router::connect('/users/users/:action/*', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users'));
Router::connect('/login', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/logout', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
Router::connect('/register', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));
Router::connect('/admin', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect('/admin/:action/*', array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'admin' => true));
```

**core.php**

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

**EDIT:**
isAuthorized() was not being called when i called the authorize = array('Controller') in the components. Had to add this in the beforeFilter() of the AppController: $this->Auth->authorize = 'Controller';

Comment: What exactly is not going? You still have no access to the admin backend? Sure the role is set and part of the auth session? Alternatively, you could leave the controllers slim and use [Tiny](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/).

Comment: No if login as a regular user I can access an admin page even though role is not admin

Answer (score 1):

In function `isAuthorized`:

```
$this->request->params['admin']
```

always not empty, so it return `true` value :)

Comment: this is not always set for me